# How to add JS messages from custom module?

Tags: magento2, module, javascript, requirejs, messages

How do I add messages using Magento 2 Ui messages to page via javascript from a custom module?

I have found a file in Magento/Ui/view/frontend/web/js/view/messages.js that appears to be responsible for adding messages to the page, in the same manner as the php message manager interface.

Am I mistaken? If not, how can it be used to add errors and success messages like the php version?

Comment: please provide more detail to your question

Comment: Hi @LM_Fielding, did you manage to find a solution for this issue?
I've stumbled upon 'Magento_Ui/js/model/messageList' myself but I can't seem to get it to work.
This is what I did:
    define(['Magento_Ui/js/model/messageList'], function(messageList) {
       messageList.addErrorMessage({
           message: 'Message to be shown.'
       });
    });

But the message is never displayed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like you're on the right way. You just need to perform the following simple steps in order to get it working.

1. Add the messages container as a child into your component. It can be
   done via js layout config.

   ```
   <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
       <item name="messages" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/view/messages</item>
           <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">messages</item>
       </item>
   </item>
   ```

   Example: [Magento_Customer::view/frontend/layout/default.xml](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/487f5f45/app/code/Magento/Customer/view/frontend/layout/default.xml#L32#L35)
2. Then add the messages block into a place where you expect to see the
   messages within your custom *KnockoutJS* template:

   ```
   <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('messages') -->
   <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
   <!--/ko-->
   ```

   Example:
   [Magento_Customer::view/frontend/web/template/authentication-popup.html](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/487f5f45/app/code/Magento/Customer/view/frontend/web/template/authentication-popup.html#L44#L46)
3. Add the messages list dependency into your js file and call the
   corresponding function: `addSuccessMessage` or `addErrorMessage`.

   ```
   define([
       'Magento_Ui/js/model/messageList'
   ], function (messageList) {
       messageList.addSuccessMessage({ message: 'Message to be shown.' });
   });
   ```

   Example: [Magento_Customer::view/frontend/web/js/action/login.js](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/487f5f45/app/code/Magento/Customer/view/frontend/web/js/action/login.js#L40)

Comment: shall I do the same thing for backend