# How to use Javascript to display page messages

Tags: magento2, javascript, messages, success-message

Is it possible to use JavaScript to display a page message?  I would like to display one when I receive an ajax response on a custom module I'm working on.

You can see an example of one of these messages after you save your user account info on the frontend.

[image]

I know I can build this markup with jQuery and add it to the page, but am wondering if Magento provides a better way of doing this.

---

I looked at `Magento_Theme/js/view/messages` and thought maybe I could include it as a dependency of my JavaScript module.  Setting the message in the jQuery `cookieStorage` [API](https://github.com/julien-maurel/jQuery-Storage-API) which Magento uses to retrieve the message info in `Magento_Theme/js/view/messages`.

```
define ([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Theme/js/view/messages',
    'jquery/jquery-storageapi',
], function ($, messages) {
    'use strict';

    return function () {
        $.cookieStorage.set('mage-messages', [{type: "success", text: "custom message text"}]);
        messages();
    }
}
```

All though this approach did not work, even though I could see that the message info was retrieved in `Magento_Theme/js/view/messages` with

```
this.cookieMessages = _.unique($.cookieStorage.get('mage-messages'), 'text');
```

It was not displayed on the frontend.

Comment: [this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/138099/how-to-add-js-messages-from-custom-module) may help you.

Answer (score 15):

Super late answer here, but this has bugged me for the longest time and I've finally found the answer. I'm just gonna clear up some stuff about the above two answers.

It really depends on where you want to show your messages. Both of the above suggestions ***work*** but it just depends on where you are on the website.

## Global Message List

From the sounds of the name, it sounds like exactly what you need. **It's not**. The name is actually super misleading. This is **only used for checkout messages**.

You can also use global message list to define a new message container on the checkout to display messages in. This is what payment gateway modules do.

Likelihood is you'll never come into contact with this.

## Customer Data

The customer data messages section is for the rest of the website. This is really what you want as you're most likely not on the checkout trying to display messages.

Customer Data *(customerData)* can get quite messy however. By using `customerData.set('messages', messages)` you are completely overwriting the messages section with your new message. This can be fine for some people, but if you have crucial messages being displayed then you don't want to be overwriting them.

To completely overwrite the customer data messages object you would do the following:

```
define(['Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'], function (customerData) {
    customerData.set('messages', {
        messages: [{
            text: 'message to display',
            type: 'success'
        }]
    });
});
```

Since this overwrites all messages, you may need to append your new message to the end of the existing messages array.

This can be done like this:

```
define(['Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'], function (customerData) {
    var customerMessages = customerData.get('messages')() || {},
        messages = customerMessages.messages || [];

    messages.push({
        text: 'message to display',
        type: 'success'
    });

    customerMessages.messages = messages;

    customerData.set('messages', customerMessages);
});
```

By doing this you're not overwriting the current messages. You could also add some duplicate message protection so that you don't end up adding the same message over and over but you don't need to do that really.

The reason for the `|| {}` and `|| []` is because sometimes there are no messages and will return `null`. If it returns `null` then it will use the blank object / array.

Comment: nice answer, I am currently using Customer Data to show success message but it is disappeared after a few seconds, do you have any solution for that?

Comment: @SagarParikhSGR This happens because you're inserting the message just before it's wiped. The messages section gets wiped when you load the page.

I got around this by creating my own message area in the same template as the already existing ones. This way, nothing from core Magento interferes with showing your messages. If you can't do that for whatever reason, you could always use a setTimeout if needed.

Comment: @DanielGlynnGoodwin Why customer-data-reload just hides messages? If it is so then what is the proper way to prevent this for particular ajax call?

Comment: @ShashankBhatt Because messages are stored in customer data and you're reloading the entirety of customer data. You shouldn't really be reloading customer data anyway. What's your use case?

Comment: HI @DanielGlynnGoodwin 
I have following code after ajax done which will show messages but due to reload, messages immediately hides as soon as they shows. Can you please suggest what should be proper workaround?

 $.ajax({
        url: someurl,
        type: "POST",
        data: form.serialize(),
    }).done(function (data) {
        if(data.success == true){
            customerData.set('messages', {
                messages: [{
                    type: 'success',
                    text: data.message
                }]
            });
        }
        return true;
});

Comment: Basically i just want to perform validation with ajax(cant done on client side due to api) and then based on that show messages, scroll to them(if long form) and hides them after stipulated time as per the normal ux flow.

Answer (score 6):

You can use something like following:

```
    define([
    'mage/url',
    'Magento_Ui/js/model/messageList'
], function (url, globalMessageList) {
    'use strict';
    return {
        /**
         * @param {Object} response
         * @param {Object} messageContainer
         */
        process: function (response, messageContainer) {
            var error;

            messageContainer = messageContainer || globalMessageList;

            if (response.status == 401) { //eslint-disable-line eqeqeq
                window.location.replace(url.build('customer/account/login/'));
            } else {
                var message = response && response.message;

                if (message) {
                    if (message.type === 'error') {
                        messageContainer.addErrorMessage({
                            message: message.text
                        });
                    } else {
                        messageContainer.addSuccessMessage({
                            message: message.text
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks that looks good, but for some reason is not working for me

Comment: Is there error? you you please add what have you tried?

Comment: its code where should be add?

Answer (score 5):

I was able to get this working by using `Magento_Customer/js/customer-data` as a dependency of my JavaScript module.  And using the `customerData.set()` function on it.

```
define ([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'Magento_Ui/js/view/messages',
    'mage/translate'
], function ($, customerData) {
    'use strict';

    return function () {
        var msg = $.mage.__('some message here');

        customerData.set('messages', {
            messages: [{
                type: 'success',
                text: msg
            }]
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: It works for me, but the notice shows for a while and suddenly gets hidden. Please let me know what I need to do to show notice same as normal magento notices work.

Comment: @DharaBhatti is this happening for you on the checkout, I remember coming across this too. Weirdly it seems to be the default behaviour of Magento, if you copy Magento_Ui/web/template/messages.html to your theme and remove `visible: isVisible()` from `<div data-role="checkout-messages" class="messages" data-bind="visible: isVisible(), click: removeAll">` it should fix it.

Comment: @DharaBhatti this probably isn't needed, the message is disappearing because the customer section is being reloaded at which point the messages are cleared. Depending on timing this is likely happening after you added the message.

Comment: @Holly Thanks for the reply. I'll try.

Comment: @DharaBhatti did you get a solution for disappeared success message too quickly? I am working on product view page, it is working fine, but message show only for few seconds

Comment: @DharaBhatti I just had the same issue with messages disappearing.  Adding `'Magento_Ui/js/view/messages'` to the define block fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

When using a quick javascript on a phtml for a feature the define way doesn't really work.
It's basically the same using require.

```javascript
require(['Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'], (customer_data) => {
var customerMessages = customer_data.get('messages')() || {},
        messages = customer_data.messages || [];

    messages.push({
        text: 'message to display',
        type: 'success'
    });

    customerMessages.messages = messages;

    customer_data.set('messages', customerMessages);
});
```

When using this the message displays instantly in the message banner from within a program flow and is easy to implement in a helper function.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Daniel Glynn Goodwin or Holly answers, I managed to keep the message displayed on the page by adding a timeout:

```
  setTimeout(function() {
          customerData.set('messages', {
                  messages: [{
                   type: 'success',
                   text: msg
                  }]
          });
 },1000);
```

So the final code would be:

```
     define ([
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
        'Magento_Ui/js/view/messages',
        'mage/translate'
    ], function ($, customerData) {
        'use strict';
    
        return function () {
            var msg = $.mage.__('some message here');
    
        setTimeout(function() {
                 customerData.set('messages', {
                      messages: [{
                          type: 'success',
                          text: msg
                      }]
                  });
            },1000);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

After the AJAX request is done, Magento automatically displays the global messages. To display a message on AJAX success/fail, you have to set it in the action instead of the template. Magento's action class, `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action` has an `\Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface` object named `$messageManager` for it. All you have to do it set the message in your AJAX handling code. Following is an example

```
class Save extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    // some code here...

    public function execute()
    {
        $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
        $location = strtolower($this->_request->getParam('location'));
        $data = [];
        if ($this->verifyValidLocation($location)) {
            $this->session->setCustomerLocation($location);
            $data = [
                'success' => true,
            ];
            //this piece of code sets the success message
            $this->messageManager->addMessage(new \Magento\Framework\Message\Success('Your location information was saved'));
        } else {
            //this piece of code sets the error message
            $this->messageManager->addMessage(new \Magento\Framework\Message\Error('Sorry, we do not deliver to your location.'));
        }
        $result->setData($data);
        return $result;
    }
    
    // rest of the class code here...
}
```

The reason why the message displayed using daniel's answer (https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/298411/42910) is removed quickly is that right after the AJAX request is completed, Magento makes an AJAX request to `/index.php/customer/section/load/?sections=messages&force_new_section_timestamp=true&_=__some_timestamp_here` to fetch current messages and then clears all currently displayed messages to displays the fetched messages. Since no message is set in the `Action`, Magento clears the currently displayed messages and then shows nothing.