# How to set success and error message when custompage ajaxcall in magento2?

Tags: magento2, ajax

I want to display success message when my custom form submitted .

I am doing ajaxcall here.

How to achieve this?

I want default page.messages not custom message div.

Comment: may be this one help you : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/237959/how-to-use-javascript-to-display-page-messages

Comment: @JimitBhavsar i have try both solution but not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know its too late, but I found it useful to share for others:

```
 define([
    'ko',
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/form',
    'Magento_Ui/js/model/messageList',
    'mage/translate',
    'moment'
 ], function(ko, $, Component, messageList, $t, moment) {}
```

This is how you will include messagelist model in your JS file. And then just add like below to show any messge:

```
messageList.addErrorMessage({
   message: $t('Something went wrong. Please contact Support team.')
});
```