# Unable to call function in ajax success in magento2

Tags: magento2, ajax, customer-data

```
I have found below error:
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined.

Code:

    <script>
require(['jquery','Magento_Customer/js/customer-data','domReady!'], function ($, customerData) {

    $(function () {

        var settings = 
            {
                url: "<?php echo $block->getUrl('customdesignsubcategories/index/save'); ?>",
                method: "POST",
                allowedTypes: "pdf, ppt, pptx,doc, docx, jpg, jpeg, png, gif, xlsx, xlsm, xlsb, xls, xltx, xltm, xlt, csv, xlam, xla, ods, zip, txt",
                maxFileSize: 26214400,
                fileName: "myfile",
                uploadStr: jQuery(".box").html(),
                multiple: true,
                nestedForms:false,
                dragDropStr:"",
                onSuccess: function (files, data, xhr)
                {
                    var file_data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);                   
                    $('<input>').attr({
                        type: 'hidden',
                        name: file_data.original + "[]",
                        value: file_data.modified
                    }).appendTo('form');
                },
                onError: function (files, status, errMsg)
                {                    
                    $("#status").html(errMsg);
                }
            };
            $("#mulitplefileuploader").uploadFile(settings);
            var dataForm = $('#customdesignsubcategories_form');
            var ignore = null;

            dataForm.mage('validation', 
            {
                ignore: ignore ? ':hidden:not(' + ignore + ')' : ':hidden'
            }).find('input:text').attr('autocomplete', 'off');

            $('#finalSubmit').click( function() 
            { 
                $('.ajax-file-upload > form > input').unwrap(); 

                if(dataForm.validation('isValid') === false)
                {
                    $("#mulitplefileuploader").uploadFile(settings);
                    return false;
                }
                if(dataForm.validation('isValid')==true)    
                {
                    console.log(customerData);
                    $.ajax({
                        type:'POST',
                        url: '<?php echo $this->getUrl("customdesignsubcategories/index/sendEmail");?>',
                        data: dataForm.serialize(),
                        dataType:'json',
                        showLoader: true ,//use for display loader
                        success: function(data){

                            if(data.status == "CaptchaError")
                            {
                                $('#customdesignsubcategories_form .invalid-captcha').show();
                                $('#customdesignsubcategories_form').find('input[name*="captcha"]').focus();
                                return false;
                            }else if(data.status=="Success")
                            {
                                var msg = 'some message here';

                                customerData.set('messages', {
                                    messages: [{
                                        type: 'success',
                                        text: msg
                                    }]
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });     
       });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you give me more information regarding this issue?

Comment: On submit of form i want to display success message using customer-data.js but reflects the error of undefined method "set" as u can see i have defined in code

Comment: can you try same script in phtml file (i.e below that form)

Comment: Yes i have put the script in phtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From magento2 phtml template you should do something like this:

```
<script>
require([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'domReady!'
], function ($, customerData) {
    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: '<?php echo $this->getUrl("customdesignsubcategories/index/sendEmail");?>',
            data: dataForm.serialize(),
            dataType:'json',
            showLoader: true ,//use for display loader
            success: function(data){

                if(data.status == "CaptchaError")
                {
                    $('#customdesignsubcategories_form .invalid-captcha').show();
                    $('#customdesignsubcategories_form').find('input[name*="captcha"]').focus();
                    return false;
                }else if(data.status=="Success")
                {
                    var msg = 'some message here';

                    customerData.set('messages', {
                        messages: [{
                            type: 'success',
                            text: msg
                        }]
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Using requirejs function to define jQuery and customerData.

Comment: I have used the same code but still issue found

Comment: Check if customerData is there: console.log(customerData);

Comment: Found undefined

Comment: I get the whole object, try clearing static folder and try in your chrome console: require('Magento_Customer/js/customer-data');

Comment: please check my edited code?

Answer (score 0):

You have not create object of `customerData` and trying to call `set` function on it. That's why the error. Please create object of `customerData` first.

What is `customerData` for you? If you have created a function named `customerData` then you can call it like:

`customerData (msg)`; // similarly send other arguments.

If you are using`customerData` as a reference to `Magento_Customer/js/customer-data` then please use following pattern to define it as dependency: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/237973/9169

Comment: Use the same code is there any other way to solve issue?